# How does SVM decide the weight/coefficient of features?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I was wondering if someone can kindly provide me with some insights regarding how linear SVM (binary classification) decides the weights for the features. Say, I have a feature $f_1$ that appears in both classes, and for simplicity, let's assume the feature values are binary. If $f_1=1$ appeared more frequently among positive training instances than among the negative ones. Would linear SVM learn a positive weight for this feature $f_1$?

Or in another word, **is there a correlation between the distribution of feature values among training samples and the weight assigned by the resulting linear SVM model?**  If so, how exactly is it?

And does dimensionality influence such correlation? (I'm thinking maybe higher dimensionality will make it harder to correlate as there could be redundant features?)

Many thanks in advance!!!